# How to locate files within my computer containing strings of text

Tags: linux, string

### What I am trying to do:

I am trying to locate files with in the directory `\\xxxx` that contain strings of text `DSN=`, `Server=`, `UID=`, `Pwd=`, `Password=`.

The files do not have to contain every single string but at least two of them.

---

The files also have to be `.config`, `.asp` or `.inc`.

---

#### How could I go about locating these files? Do I need software, a certain coding language, etc..

Comment: http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack would work

Comment: Here is an example: `find / -name "*.config" -exec grep -El "(DSN|Server|UID|Pwd|Password)=" {} \;`. Use it wisely and go from there.

Comment: @SamiLaine If you post your answer, I will upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Basic method to search for string is to use grep. Something like "grep "DSN=" \xxxx" would search for the first string. To use both, you can pass -E: "grep -E ' DSN=|Server=' \xxxx"